# Upload CSV file to MySQL using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, csv, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to upload a `csv` file to the table `users` in Laravel.

This is my `php` script:

```
private function _import_csv($path, $filename)
    {

        $csv = $path . $filename;
        $query = sprintf("LOAD DATA local INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE users FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 0 LINES (`firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `gender`, `email`, `country`, `ethnicity`, `education`  )", addslashes($csv));
    return DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);

}



public function uploadUsers(){


    if (Input::hasFile('fileInput')){

        $file = Input::file('fileInput');
        $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $path = 'public/uploads/'.date('Y/m/');

        $file->move($path, $name);
        $this->_import_csv($path, $name);

    }

    return Response::json(["success"=>true]);
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"PDO::exec(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\lc2\\laravel\\app\\controllers\\UsersController.php","line":224}}
```

I don't know whats wrong. Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Please try it

Set PDO Connection options

Set attribute **PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE** in **database.php**

```
'mysql' => array(
            ....
            'options'    => [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE=>true],
        ),
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to clean the query string before the sprintf function.